# JasperServer blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'

Tags: apache, tomcat, cors, jasperserver

I'm trying to enable CORS policy in the jasperserver.

I'm using angular HTTPClient to call the API coming from the jasperserver.

Things that I have tried so far.

Modifying the apache-tomcat apache-tomcat\conf\web.xml file
and addding the code below.

```html
<filter>
    <filter-name>CorsFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.apache.catalina.filters.CorsFilter</filter-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>cors.allowed.origins</param-name>
        <param-value>*</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>cors.allowed.headers</param-name>
        <param-value>Content-Type,X-Requested-With,Accept,Authorization,Origin,Access-Control-Request-Method,Access-Control-Request-Headers</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>cors.exposed.headers</param-name>
        <param-value>Access-Control-Allow-Origin,Access-Control-Allow-Credentials</param-value>
    </init-param>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>CorsFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern> /* </url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

which is from the [apache-tomcat](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/filter.html#CORS_Filter) site.

Also tried to modify the  jasperserver\WEB-INF\Web.xml file
 and adding the code below

```html
<filter>
<filter-name>CorsFilter2</filter-name>
<filter-class>org.apache.catalina.filters.CorsFilter</filter-class>
<init-param>
<param-name>cors.allowed.origins</param-name>
<param-value>*</param-value>
</init-param>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
<filter-name>CorsFilter</filter-name>
<url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

---

And still no luck and encountering this error.

[image: Error Encountered]

Comment: There are multiple points here. First, you can try to add `cors.allowed.methods` to your filter. It might be needed since as per specification CORS start with `OPTIONS` request. Second, remove spaces from `<url-pattern>` as mentioned in your first config. Third, you tried a new config but it seems you never changed `<url-pattern>` to use your `CorsFilter2`, it was still mapped to `CorsFilter`. Lastly, try to hit your 8082 port directly from some REST client if the headers in response contain necessary Access-Control-* headers.

Comment: @Siddharth I have tried what you have said, but it still not working

Answer (score 0):

After struggling for a couple of hours with this, i have it figured out.

You have to disable Jasper's built in CorsFilter altogether, along with adding/mapping your own filter in your tomcat's `/webapps/jasperserver/WEB-INF/web.xml`. No intervention is needed in the global tomcat web.xml.

```
<!-- Comment the built-in filter out.
    <filter>
       <filter-name>CorsFilter</filter-name>
       <filter-class>com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.api.security.csrf.CorsFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>
    -->

    <filter>
        <filter-name>CorsFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.apache.catalina.filters.CorsFilter</filter-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>cors.allowed.origins</param-name>
            <!-- Tomcat 8.5+ doesn't allow '*' any longer in conjuction with 'cors.support.credentials' set to true.
             Instead, a specific comma separated list has to be set here. See https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=62343 -->
            <param-value>http://localhost:9000</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>cors.allowed.methods</param-name>
            <param-value>GET,POST,HEAD,OPTIONS,PUT</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>cors.allowed.headers</param-name>
            <!--- If requests contain an authorization header, it has to be added here as well -->
            <param-value>
                Content-Type,X-Requested-With,Accept,Origin,Access-Control-Request-Method,Access-Control-Request-Headers,X-Remote-Domain,Authorization
            </param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>cors.exposed.headers</param-name>
            <param-value>Access-Control-Allow-Origin,Access-Control-Allow-Credentials</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>cors.support.credentials</param-name>
            <param-value>true</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>cors.preflight.maxage</param-name>
            <param-value>10</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </filter>                
        .......

        <!-- Ensure your newly introduced mapping is first in line -->
            <filter-mapping>
                <filter-name>CorsFilter</filter-name>
                <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
            </filter-mapping>

        <!-- Also comment out any existing mappings for the built-in filter -->
        <!--
          <filter-mapping>
              <filter-name>CorsFilter</filter-name>
              <url-pattern>*.woff</url-pattern>
          </filter-mapping>
          <filter-mapping>
              <filter-name>CorsFilter</filter-name>
              <url-pattern>*.ttf</url-pattern>
          </filter-mapping>
          <filter-mapping>
              <filter-name>CorsFilter</filter-name>
              <url-pattern>*.svg</url-pattern>
          </filter-mapping>
          <filter-mapping>
              <filter-name>CorsFilter</filter-name>
              <url-pattern>*.eot</url-pattern>
          </filter-mapping>
        -->
```

Comment: @davecar21 For your additional info, my jasper server is a docker container, using bitnami's image v7.1.1. I overrode the web.xml using a host mounted volume, made the changes displayed above and that did the trick for me. That specific value in `cors.allowed.origins` was also crucial, since `*` is no longer accepted.

Comment: done that..didn't work. Mine is on premise 7.2 running on Windows

Comment: didn't work - even didn't have such filter in web.xml on v7.8.0 - could be removed by CI configs though